# Could not build wheels for aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

```
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I installed vs tools C++ desktop development, NET, and node.js

Comment: what's your python version? Also post full error message